# fixed position sidebar with content responsive

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble understanding some css with responsive design. Basically I want a fixed position sidebar on the left with the content on the right, the content on the right is responsive. when I scale the browser the content box goes behind the sidebar as opposed to scaling down itself. I just can't get the css right.

here's what I have so far.

```
.sidebar {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top:0;
height: 100%;
background: url(../images/sidebar.png) repeat-y top left;
width: 225px;
}


.content {
width: 45%;
float: left;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}
```

the sidebar div is above the container div and above the content div,  any help would be amazing as I'm starting to lose hair :(

Comment: can you please show fiddle for better understating?

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle example?

Comment: can you show us your live demo code ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont write your html here .

I guess you can fix the problem by magin :

```
.content {
width: 45%;
float: left;
margin-left:230px;
}
```